# Should I enable VR support for google cardboard in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-cardboard, virtual-reality, google-vr

I'm creating my firs VR app i unity for google cardboard. I noticed VR support setting in the inspector. I searched a little bit and it isn't clear for me if I should enable it for google cardboard. [Here](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/VROverview.html) is the link for unity manual about it. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a while you should not enable VR support since Unity has no native support for Cardboard yet, although it was announced on Vision Summit 2016 for future versions.

By now, you should only use the Unity package with the appropriated prefabs for Google Cardboard available at https://developers.google.com/vr/unity/download.

Answer (score 1):

You dont need to check Virtual Reality Supported to make an app for Google Cardboard. Make sure that you download the Google VR SDK for Unity and bring it in your assets folder in your project. Then just search for GVR Main in your assets folder and bring that into your project scene and you are good to go. Also you may not need the default camera in the scene as well. Just create your scene and your build is automatically supported for Google Cardboard. VR Supported is largely for computer dependent devices like the Oculus Rift and not apps that you run on your mobile phones.

Comment: And what about this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44135605/missing-gvrmain-file-in-unity#comment75381330_44135605
Could you help?

Comment: @VladyslavUlianytskyi Thanks for referring.. Check the comment on the same thread. If it still does not work, then let me know.