# missing GVRMain file in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-cardboard, virtual-reality

I am trying to create a Google Cardboard app using Unity.  The new SDK doesn't have GVRMain, so I used GVREditorEmulator instead.  However, I can't "look around" in the project.  I am using a Windows PC, and Unity 5.6

Comment: Facing the same problem. Watched tutorials and videos about VR, and everywhere there is GVRMain after import in project GoogleVRForUnity package. But there is only GVREditorEmulator

Comment: Hi guys.. I imported the latest GVR1.5 SDK in Unity 5.6 and it runs fine on my system, I'm able to look around fine in the editor.
Just to make sure.. GVREditorEmulator works like GVRViewerMain and not like GVRMain which means the you can work with the default camera and just add this prefab to your hierarchy. It does not come with a camera of its own.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like Google updated its GoogleVR SDK and GvrViewerMain is replaced by GvrEditorEmulator. 
https://developers.google.com/vr/unity/release-notes

Comment: Older version of the Google VR:
https://github.com/googlevr/gvr-unity-sdk/releases

Answer (score 0):

What you're most likely missing is the Camera script which has to talk to the Gvr Editor Emulator.

Click on the GvrEditorEmulator

In the inspector see Camera: None (Camera)

This is where your camera should be referenced.

Comment: There is Main Camera only, but its not helped

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get around the problem by downloading an older version of the Google VR plugin for Unity that had the GVRMain file.  I would love a solution for the new version though.

Answer (score 0):

There is no longer a need for GVRViewerMain, you simply configure the VR SDK in Player Settings > Other Settings > Virtual Reality SDKs: add Daydream and/or Cardboard as appropriate for your project. Your main camera will automatically become a VR camera since cardboard is now native to unity. Hope this helps.